# Preload replace not evaluating variable outside of pair

Tags: channel-entries, categories, variable, preload-replace

I am trying to get the current entry's category so I can make a comparison inside a menu elsewhere to see if the menu item is for the current page. I have the following code at the top of my template:

```
{exp:channel:entries}
    {categories limit="1"}
        {preload_replace:current_category="{category_id}"}  
        {current_category}                      
    {/categories}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

which gives an output of `56`

However, if I move `{current_category}` out of the pair so I can use it elsewhere, it does not evaluate:

```
{exp:channel:entries}
    {categories limit="1"}
        {preload_replace:current_category="{category_id}"}  
    {/categories}
{/exp:channel:entries}
{current_category}
```

gives an output of `{category_id}`

How can I get the replace variable to save the evaluated category_id inside of the pair so I can use it elsewhere? Or, is there a better way to be doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a better way, though I'm not sure what where you're trying to insert the entry's category_id.

Use [Stash](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/stash), you'll be glad you did.

```
{exp:channel:entries}
  {exp:stash:set name="category_id"}
    {categories limit="1"}
      {category_id}                  
    {/categories}
  {/exp:stash:set}
{/exp:channel:entries} 

<!-- Then get it after entries loop -->
{exp:stash:get name="category_id"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using an embed.

```
{embed="group/.template" current_category="{exp:channel:entries}{categories limit="1"}{category_id}{/categories}{/exp:channel:entries}" }
```

On the embed template, just call {embed:current_category}.

I think it's better than install stash for use just once.

Comment: I like this as well but now that I've gotten the hang of Stash, I'm using it all over the place! :)

Comment: I have thinking that stash is really overused. Other day I saw a really so amazing complex template all built in the power of Stash. Sometimes it can be great, but too much power can be dangerous. I have made this mistake, too, sometime ago. After some time, my template was too complex to keep working on it. Now, I prefer use addons just when I really need then. Have a nice day!